# Tax rates in Magento for EU and Rest Of World

Tags: magento

As a UK VAT registered business selling outwith the UK I have created a tax rate based on the UK VAT rate for all EU countries. Out-with the EU no VAT will be charged so am I correct in thinking I don't have to create any further rates, and that a user buying from the Rest Of World will just not have no tax rule applied so no VAT will be added nor will a tax element appear in their invoice breakdown (VAT breakdown is enabled in the config)?

Answer (score 1):

An up to date CSV for EU tax rates in 2014 that works with Magento 1.9.0.1 (note that this is the current UK VAT rate of 20%). You should not be charging VAT when you *ship* to countries outside of the EU zone- ignore their billing address, it is where you send the items that counts. It should also be noted that Iceland, Liechtenstein, Norway and Switzerland are exempt from UK VAT.

```
Code,Country,State,Zip/Post Code,Rate,Zip/Post is Range,Range From,Range To,default
GB,GB,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
AL,AL,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
AD,AD,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
AT,AT,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
BY,BY,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
BE,BE,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
BA,BA,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
BG,BG,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
HR,HR,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
CY,CY,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
CZ,CZ,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
DK,DK,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
EE,EE,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
FO,FO,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
FI,FI,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
FR,FR,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
DE,DE,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
GI,GI,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
GR,GR,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
HU,HU,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
IS,IS,*,,0.0000,,,,VAT
IE,IE,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
IT,IT,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
LV,LV,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
LB,LB,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
LI,LI,*,,0.0000,,,,VAT
LT,LT,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
LU,LU,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
MT,MT,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
MD,MD,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
MC,MC,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
ME,ME,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
NL,NL,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
NO,NO,*,,0.0000,,,,VAT
PL,PL,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
PT,PT,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
RO,RO,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
RS,RS,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
SK,SK,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
SI,SI,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
ES,ES,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
SJ,SJ,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
SE,SE,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
CH,CH,*,,0.0000,,,,VAT
TR,TR,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
UA,UA,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
VA,VA,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
```

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, both those answers are incorrect. I'm fairly certain that as UK businesses we have to charge UK VAT only to the UK and other members of the EU, and zero rate to any country outside the EU. Both answers include non-EU countries in the csv, including AL (Albania), AD (Andorra), BY (Belarus), BA (Bosnia & Herzegovina), etc, etc.

Here's my edited list, although I'm not sure about VA (Vatican City), it seems to officially not be part of the EU, so in theory zero rated, can anyone clarify? (Not that I've ever had an order from there!)

```
Code,Country,State,Zip/Post Code,Rate,Zip/Post is Range,Range From,Range To,default
GB,GB,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
AT,AT,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
BE,BE,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
BG,BG,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
CY,CY,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
CZ,CZ,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
DK,DK,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
EE,EE,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
FI,FI,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
FR,FR,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
DE,DE,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
GI,GI,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
GR,GR,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
HR,HR,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
HU,HU,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
IE,IE,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
IT,IT,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
LV,LV,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
LI,LI,*,,0.0000,,,,VAT
LT,LT,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
LU,LU,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
MT,MT,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
MC,MC,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
NL,NL,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
NO,NO,*,,0.0000,,,,VAT
PL,PL,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
PT,PT,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
RO,RO,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
SK,SK,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
SI,SI,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
ES,ES,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
SE,SE,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
CH,CH,*,,0.0000,,,,VAT
VA,VA,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
```